# create session after old session is timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have a snippet that a session has numeric content nd it incrise to 3 but when it recieve to 3 it send to client.this session must time out in 1 minuet but until the session is not time out the program work correctly but when the session is expired and new session want create i get system.invalidoperationexception  whats the problem???? its my code ?

```
 string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;


           HttpContext failuser = HttpContext.Current;
           failuser.Session.Timeout =1;
           if (failuser != null)
           {
               if (failuser.Session[ip] != null)
                   failuser.Session[ip] = (int)failuser.Session[ip] + 1;
               else
                   failuser.Session[ip] = 1;

               // 
               retval = failuser.Session[ip].ToString();
               if ((int)failuser.Session[ip] > 2)
               {

                   retval = "!";

               }
```

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? I mean when you debugged the code in which location you got this exception?

Comment: thank for reply ;this code is in webmethod i call it in jquery ajax method

Comment: i use breakpoint but  dont fall in it when exception occure

Comment: okay @quantum62, try remove the check of "failuser != null" and run the code once again.

Comment: i get authentication exception . can it be associated with  sessions cookies?why when i refresh page in adressbar problem is soved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to maintain any session state after it expires.
A session timeout of 1 minute is very small. Keep it at something higher like 5 minutes.

It would be lot easier to not allow your session to timeout, rather than restore the session to the state where it was after a timeout.

Since you are already using WebMethods, you could extend the life of the session by posting back just before it expires. (Be sure to keep an absolute timeout, say after 30 mins if your user is inactive).

Comment: i dont want session has a long life time. my problem  it is: when i want create new sesion i get system.invalidoperationexception if i select adress bar and reload page new session create but when i use window.location.reload() in client side for refresh my problem dont solve.

Comment: i wanna know what happend that wen i reload handy in browser dosenot exist any problem but when i use methods like reload or history.go(0) ,problem remain